# Calculate the number of equivalence relations $S$ that satisfies $R \subseteq S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and let $R=\{(1,2),(5,4),(4,5),(6,2),(4,4),(6,5),(7,8)\}$ be a relation on A.

What it the number of equivalence relations $S$ that satisfies $R \subseteq S$

I know what an equivalence relation is, but I'm kinda lost in this exercise.. I have no idea how to calculate this.
I know that if $(1,2) \in S$, then I'm committed to also take $(2,1)$.. but counting like this won't get me nowhere.

Can anyone show me how to solve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: $R \subseteq S$ or $S \subseteq R$? Your question does not match your title...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of $R$, we must have $1=2=4=5=6$, $7=8$, and $3=3$.  So there are at most three equivalence classes.  You can also combine them in various ways, e.g. $1=2=4=5=6$ and $3=7=8$.

Comment: I second this. It's better to look at the equivalence classes than directly at the equivalence relations.

Comment: Let me see if I understood you, so the total number of relations that could be is: $2^3-1$? since I want to take the total possible groupings that these classes could have? (size of power set minus the empty set)

Comment: Why 7?  There are three groups, ABC.  We could have A=B, or A=C, or B=C, or A=B=C, or all three distinct.  That makes 5.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helped.
Can you please show me an explanation how to calculate this in terms of combinatorics? because it's easy to calc if you only have 3 equivalence classes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set